# largest and second largest number getting same value from integer array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

here i have written code to print largest and second largest number from array.But when i have largest number two times in my array then its printing both largest and second largest as same.Can anybody tell me where I'm doing mistakes.This is my code.

```
int arr[] = {96, 1, 23, 47, 81, 92, 52, 48, 56, 66, 65, 96, 81, 6};
    int largest = arr[0];
    int secondLargest = arr[0];
    // check the condition
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // this condition check for largest number
        if (arr[i] > largest) {
            secondLargest = largest;
            largest = arr[i];

        } else if (arr[i] > secondLargest) {
            secondLargest = arr[i];

        }
    }
    // print the result
    System.out.println("second largest number is:" + secondLargest);
    System.out.println("largest number is:" + largest);
```

and output coming as:

```
second largest number is:96
largest number is:96
```

Comment: Why don't you sort it and return first and second values?

Comment: Well you're initial assumption that largest = secondLargest = arr[0] before iterating through the array values is already false.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Why would you sort an array for a task like that? `O(n)` vs `O(nlogn)` (and I think it's an exercise also)

Comment: @MarounMaroun,i dont want to use predefined or existed java api.so i have written like this.

Comment: @user2336315 because I don't really care about O(n) vs O(nlogn) for sorting small array.. it won't really make big difference.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Seems like an exercise, so calling sort and then pick the two first values would defeat all the purpose of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues:

1) the initialization of the largest and second largest (use  Integer.MIN_VALUE); You are setting the second largest at your first iteration and it is the largest number in array

2) the condition for setting secondLargest; you should also check: arr[i] < largest

```
    int arr[] = {96, 1, 23, 47, 81, 92, 52, 48, 56, 66, 65, 96, 81, 6};
    int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int secondLargest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    // check the condition
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // this condition check for largest number
        if (arr[i] > largest) {
            secondLargest = largest;
            largest = arr[i];
        } else if (arr[i] > secondLargest && arr[i] < largest) {
            secondLargest = arr[i];
        }
    }
```

output:

```
second largest number is:92
largest number is:96
```

Comment: user1121883,how can i print small number from the above code?

Comment: @khanam the smallest and the second smallest?

Comment: @Khanam that's easy; replace:   int largest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int secondLargest = Integer.MAX_VALUE; and switch some checks   if (arr[i] < largest) {
                secondLargest = largest;
                largest = arr[i];
            } else if (arr[i] < secondLargest && arr[i] > largest) {
                secondLargest = arr[i];
            } ; of course is better to rename variable names accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing `largest` and `secondLargest` to the first element of the array, so if the first element is already the largest, both would hold the largest in the end.

A better initialization is to set them to a real small value :

```
int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int secondLargest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int arr[] = {96, 1, 23, 47, 81, 92, 52, 48, 56, 66, 65, 96, 81, 6};
```

There are two numbers with the value 96. So after 96 > 96 fails, it goes to the condition of arr[i] > secondLargest and it passes that test. That's why you'll have the largest and secondLargest as the same number, 96.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the binarySearch

```
int arr[] = {96, 1, 23, 47, 81, 92, 52, 48, 56, 66, 65, 96, 81, 6};
Arrays.sort(arr);
int largest = arr[arr.length - 1];
int binarySearch = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, largest);
System.out.println("largest        = " + largest);
// need to handle the case for arrays which are...
// - empty
// - contain only one int
// - the largest int is on index zero
System.out.println("second largest = " + arr[binarySearch - 1]);
```